# background image not repeating on absolute element

Tags: html, css

The background image (the topography) is not repeating. It stops above the 
 "Terra management technique" (look at pic). I want to cover the entire element (accordion), which is the element right above the footer.

[image: webpage]

HTML

```
<div class="accordion">
  <span class"topography"><img src="/img/bg/topo.svg"/></span>
  .....
</div>
```

CSS

```
.accordion {
  position: relative;
}

.topography {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
pointer-events: none;
background-repeat: repeat;
}

.topography img{
height: 100%;
background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: You're missing an `=` and you don't apply `background-repeat` to an `img` itself, you apply it to an element with a `background-image` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXONxM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the image as a background-image then, not as an img tag:

```
<div class="accordion">
  <span class"topography"></span>
  .....
</div>

CSS

.accordion {
  position: relative;
}

.topography {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
pointer-events: none;
background-image: url("/img/bg/topo.svg");
background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: well, what if I am receiving the url from the react state in jsx and then isnt't it is compulsory to use `img` tag? what should I do in that case?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `background-repeat` for  tag.

instead of `<img>` use CSS to load image using `background-image` or use `background` in single line to merge all your background property

```
.topography {
   background: url('/img/bg/topo.svg') repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You remove the image in your html and set the `background-image` property in your CSS file.

Like this:

```css
.topography {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS1EwO-OcUp2ZTpjubUsiZPLm8RAej4XQLnKs5s3Ry5kAd8IEVT");
  /*relative link (from your css file location) to your background image*/
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="topography">
  <p>What ever here is</p>
  <p>What ever here is 2</p>
  <p>What ever here is 3</p>
</div>
```